# Dynamic Angular and Ionic checkbox list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework

I have my app in Ionic and Angular. I have a list with checkbox items that come from an array. What I want is when the user clicks on a checkbox item, they are added to a separate list i.e my choices.

the code is: 
App.js

```
$scope.myList = [
{name:'Choice one'},
{name:'Choice two)'}
];
```

HTML VIEW:

```
  <div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat='item in myList | filter: search'>
  <label class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.myList[$index]">
  </label>
       <p ng-bind-html="item.name"></p>

    </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

So I want the choices once clicked to be added to a list above which is similar code to the html above. Any ideas?

Comment: as far as i understand? you want to attach checkbox value (checked or not) to each object in myList ?

Comment: Yes but if u imagine the list of choices is seperate and once they click on a choice it is added to another list in a div above saying my Choices

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
$scope.myList = [
                    {name:'Choice one'},
                    {name:'Choice two)'}
                ];

$scope.myChoices = [];

$scope.stateChanged = function(checked){
    if(checked){
        $scope.myChoices.push(checked);
    }else{
        var index = $scope.myChoices.indexOf(checked);
        $scope.myChoices.splice(index,1);
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat='item in myList | filter: search'>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.myList[$index]" ng-change='stateChanged(option.myList[$index])'>
            </label>
            <p ng-bind-html="item.name"></p>
        </li>
        <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Abduallah, what if I want it in a seperate div above this list?

Comment: Hi Abduallah, but for some reason the code above does not keep the ng-model="option.myList[$index]". (LocalStorage);

Answer (score 0):

See this demo with your code : http://play.ionic.io/app/89d16b54285b

You do not need to make a seperate list to show selected options somewhere else. Just attach `selected` property with each object this way `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">`

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat='item in myList | filter: search'>
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">
    </label>
       <p ng-bind-html="item.name"></p>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Now you can use same `myList` anywhere to see which is selected using filter

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in myList | filter:{selected:true}">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: With the code above there is nothing for local storage? which I use with ng-model="option.myList[$index]". How would this be implemented also

Comment: Have you seen demo which i mentioned in my answer? and what do you mean by local storage?

Comment: I am using ng-model="option.myList[$index]" for localStorage how do i use this with your code?

Comment: as i told `myList` has both information now. Your datastructure will be [{name: 'choice1', selected: false},{name: 'choice2', selected: false}], now those object which are selected will have `selected:true` value. You can use myList also to store in localstorage. Point is you do not need to use extra array to store selected options.

Comment: Its working but can you show how you mean with the local storage?

Comment: Please make some separate question and write your code what you have attempted and what you are trying to achieve with localstorage as this question is related to dynamic checkboxes. All i can tell now that you have `$scope.myList` and store it in localstorage.

Comment: in app.js i have: $scope.option = $localStorage;